# vi editor paste text from some page into vi editor page

Tags: unix, vi

I'm trying to paste text into heroku vi editor, like the code snippet from facebook tutorial, but I cant seem to figure it out.
I have tried

```
 :"*P
 :"*p
 :p
```

etc, i'm using windows 7 for all it matters? any ideas

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_the_Windows_clipboard_in_Cygwin_Vim

Answer (score 1):

open the vi editor, you want to start with an empty, unnamed document

```
type ':set noai nosm' (without the single-quotes) (you need the ':' char)
press the enter key
press the letter i (for insert)
now use the appropriate mouse click to paste your text
type ':wq myFileName.php' (no single-quotes)
# this 'w'rites the filename and 'q'uits the editor
```

Now you should have a file with the code you wanted.

Incidentally, this doesn't really qualify as a programming question, in the future, use the related site, superuser.com to post this sort of question.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

at first You have to copy the text to the buffer pressing yy on the line you want to copy, after that You will be able to paste it anywhere with p .

Hope it helps :)

Comment: i'm copying text from a webpage?!

Answer (score 0):

Just select and copy normally from the webpage ..And right click at the cursor position you want to paste at in your Unix terminal..(i.e vi editor) .

It'll get pasted.

Comment: well it doens't, i cant paste anything in heroku vi editor, besides what I copy from there.